# How to registered 'apoc.algo.dijkstra' in neo4j embedded application?

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I use java neo4j embedded version in my application.

when i use `db.execute(CypherQuery)` to execute

```
CALL apoc.algo.dijkstra(m, n, 'IS_CONNECTED', 'cost') YIELD path, weight RETURN path, weight ORDER BY weight limit 1
```

than i found

```
Caused by: org.neo4j.internal.kernel.api.exceptions.ProcedureException: There is no procedure with the name `apoc.algo.dijkstra` registered for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.ProcedureRegistry.noSuchProcedure(ProcedureRegistry.java:276)
```

So i want to know how can i registered the apoc jar for the embedded neo4j.